# Creating copy of CMSampleBuffer in Swift returns OSStatus -12743 (Invalid Media Format)

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, core-video, core-media, cmsamplebuffer

I am attempting to perform a deep clone of `CMSampleBuffer` to store the output of a `AVCaptureSession`. I am receiving the error `kCMSampleBufferError_InvalidMediaFormat` `(OSStatus -12743)` when I run the function `CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer`. I don't see how I've mismatched the `CVImageBuffer` and the `CMSampleBuffer` format description. Anyone know where I've gone wrong? Her is my test code.

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    let allocator: CFAllocator = CFAllocatorGetDefault().takeRetainedValue()

    func cloneImageBuffer(imageBuffer: CVImageBuffer!) -> CVImageBuffer? {
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)
        let bytesPerRow: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
        let width: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
        let height: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)
        let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)
        let pixelFormatType = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(imageBuffer)

        let data = NSMutableData(bytes: baseAddress, length: bytesPerRow * height)
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)

        var clonedImageBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
        let refCon = NSMutableData()

        if CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(allocator, width, height, pixelFormatType, data.mutableBytes, bytesPerRow, nil, refCon.mutableBytes, nil, &clonedImageBuffer) == noErr {
            return clonedImageBuffer
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    if let oldImageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
        if let newImageBuffer = cloneImageBuffer(oldImageBuffer) {
            if let formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer) {
                let dataIsReady = CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer)
                let refCon = NSMutableData()
                var timingInfo: CMSampleTimingInfo = kCMTimingInfoInvalid
                let timingInfoSuccess = CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfo(sampleBuffer, 0, &timingInfo)
                if timingInfoSuccess == noErr {
                    var newSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?
                    let success = CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(allocator, newImageBuffer, dataIsReady, nil, refCon.mutableBytes, formatDescription, &timingInfo, &newSampleBuffer)
                    if success == noErr {
                        bufferArray.append(newSampleBuffer!)
                    } else {
                        NSLog("Failed to create new image buffer. Error: \(success)")
                    }
                } else {
                    NSLog("Failed to get timing info. Error: \(timingInfoSuccess)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by creating a format description off the newly created image buffer and using it instead of the format description off the original sample buffer. Unfortunately while that fixes the problem here, the format descriptions don't match and causes problem further down.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across the same issue. After a bit of investigation, the `CMVideoFormatDescriptionMatchesImageBuffer()` function documentation gave a bit of insight.

> This function uses the keys returned by CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetExtensionKeysCommonWithImageBuffers to compares the extensions of the given format description to the attachments of the given image buffer (if an attachment is absent in either it must be absent in both). It also checks kCMFormatDescriptionExtension_BytesPerRow against CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow, if applicable.

In my case, I didn't copy over some of the format description extensions as CVBuffer attachments of the copied pixel buffer. Running this bit of code after creating the new CVPixelBufferRef resolved the issue for me (Objective-C, but shouldn't be hard to convert to Swift)

```
NSSet *commonKeys = [NSSet setWithArray:(NSArray *)CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetExtensionKeysCommonWithImageBuffers()];
NSDictionary *attachments = (NSDictionary *)CVBufferGetAttachments(originalPixelBuffer, kCVAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
[attachments enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
{
    if ([commonKeys containsObject:key])
    {
        CVBufferSetAttachment(pixelBufferCopy, (__bridge CFStringRef)(key), (__bridge CFTypeRef)(obj), kCVAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
    }
}];
attachments = (NSDictionary *)CVBufferGetAttachments(originalPixelBuffer, kCVAttachmentMode_ShouldNotPropagate);
[attachments enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
{
    if ([commonKeys containsObject:key])
    {
        CVBufferSetAttachment(pixelBufferCopy, (__bridge CFStringRef)(key), (__bridge CFTypeRef)(obj), kCVAttachmentMode_ShouldNotPropagate);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The Swift version for the answer of Raymanman.

```swift
let commonKeys = NSSet(array: CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetExtensionKeysCommonWithImageBuffers() as! [Any])

let propagatedAttachments = NSDictionary(dictionary: CVBufferGetAttachments(pixelBuffer, .shouldPropagate)!)
propagatedAttachments.enumerateKeysAndObjects { key, obj, stop in
    if commonKeys.contains(key) {
        CVBufferSetAttachment(outputPixelBuffer, key as! CFString, obj as AnyObject, .shouldPropagate)
    }
}

let nonPropagatedAttachments = NSDictionary(dictionary: CVBufferGetAttachments(pixelBuffer, .shouldPropagate)!)
nonPropagatedAttachments.enumerateKeysAndObjects { key, obj, stop in
    if commonKeys.contains(key) {
        CVBufferSetAttachment(outputPixelBuffer, key as! CFString, obj as AnyObject, .shouldNotPropagate)
    }
}
```